# Performing Functions on Multi-Index Column Dataframe based on Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                   |    PACKAGES SHIPPED     |    PACKAGES TRANSFERRED   |
Product & Quantity | Apple-5 pk | Apple-5 pk | Apple-5 pk  |  Apple-5pk  |
Store Branch I.D.  |  34234324  |  34235555  |  34234324   |  34235555   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Period Week     
   5/14 - 5/20     |     5      |     10     |     20      |     7       |
   5/21 - 5/27     |     40     |      X     |      1      |     Y       |
```

This Dataframe has multi-column headers of "packages shipped", where there are many store branches that will all have 'packages shipped'.

If I wanted to sum "Packages Shipped" and "Packages Transferred" for a specific "Product & Quantity" value and for a specific "Store & Branch ID", for each period week, what would be the most efficient way to do this?

The result dataframe ideally would be:

```
                   |Sum Shipped & Transferred|Sum Shipped & Transferred  |                     
Product & Quantity |       Apple-5 pk        |         Apple-10 pk       |
Store Branch I.D.  |  34234324  |  34235555  |  34234324   |  34235555   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Period Week     
   5/14 - 5/20     |     25     |     17     |     40      |     234     |
   5/21 - 5/27     |     41     |     X+Y    |     34      |      25     |
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to consider representing this as a dataframe instead of as a picture.  Here's a simple way to consider your problem.  Of course, if you truly have the data stored with multi-column indexes as represented in your picture, then this won't be of any help.

```
In [33]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Period Week':['5/14 - 5/20','5/21 - 5/27','5/14 - 5/20','5/21 - 5/27'],'Transaction':['Shi
    ...: pped','Shipped','Transfered','Transfered'],'Package SKU':['Apples-5k','Apples-10k','Apples-5k','Apples-10k'],'
    ...: Quantity':[5,10,20,7]})

In [34]: df
Out[34]:
   Period Week Transaction Package SKU  Quantity
0  5/14 - 5/20     Shipped   Apples-5k         5
1  5/21 - 5/27     Shipped  Apples-10k        10
2  5/14 - 5/20  Transfered   Apples-5k        20
3  5/21 - 5/27  Transfered  Apples-10k         7
```

Then setting the index to be multi-column:

```
df.set_index(['Period Week','Transaction','Package SKU'])
```

Finally, groupby and calc

```
In [35]: df.groupby(['Period Week','Package SKU'])['Quantity'].count()
Out[35]:
Period Week  Package SKU
5/14 - 5/20  Apples-5k      2
5/21 - 5/27  Apples-10k     2
Name: Quantity, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I actually do have the data stored in multi-indexed columns like the picture. Do you possibly have some advice/insight into how perform the sums based on the original dataframe?

Comment: So are you suggesting you already have a multiindex dataframe?  Maybe it would help if you provided the code to create the dataframe you are working on.  If it already has a hierarchical index then slicing should be pretty straightforward.